# elasticsearch: using nested agg after reverse_nested shows higher count than expected

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch 2.2.0, I am doing this:

1. Grouping by a nested field: **nested_path.nested_field**
2. Using a `reverse_nested` agg so I can apply this filter: **non_nested_field == "yay"**
3. Using a `nested` agg so I can then get a count of the nested field I am grouping by: **nested_path.nested_field**

Problem:  By using the `reverse_nested` agg I am getting a higher doc_count than I would expect.

Here is the mapping and docs I am indexing:

```
PUT /my_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
         "properties": {
            "nested_path": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "nested_field": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
               }
            },
            "non_nested_field": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

POST /my_index/my_type/1
{
  "non_nested_field": "whoray",
  "nested_path": [
    {
      "nested_field": "yes"
    },
    {
      "nested_field": "yes"
    },
    {
      "nested_field": "no"
    }
  ]
}

POST /my_index/my_type/2
{
  "non_nested_field": "yay",
  "nested_path": [
    {
      "nested_field": "maybe"
    },
    {
      "nested_field": "no"
    }
  ]
}
```

Request body:

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "aggs": {
      "nested_option": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "nested_path"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "group_list": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "nested_path.nested_field",
                  "size": 100
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "level_1": {
                     "reverse_nested": {},
                     "aggs": {
                        "level_2": {
                           "filter": {
                              "term": {
                                 "non_nested_field": "yay"
                              }
                           },
                           "aggs": {
                              "level_3": {
                                 "nested": {
                                    "path": "nested_path"
                                 },
                                 "aggs": {
                                    "stat": {
                                       "value_count": {
                                          "field": "nested_path.nested_field"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 0
}
```

Part of the response I get is this:

```
{  
  "aggregations": {
    "nested_option": {
      "doc_count": 5,
      "group_list": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "no",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "level_1": {
              "doc_count": 2,
              "level_2": {
                "doc_count": 1,
                "level_3": {
                  "doc_count": 2,
                  "stat": {
                    "value": 2
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          //.... 
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the first element of the **buckets** array in the response, **level_1.level_2.doc_count** is 1, and this is correct, because there's only one of the two docs indexed where **nested_path.nested_field == "no"** and **non_nested_field == "yay"**.  But **level_1.level_2.level_3.doc_count** in the response is 2.  It should only be 1.  This seems like a bug to me.